# a table with one column only?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

What is the use of a table with only one column?

```
TableName
----------
Table_PK
```

Say I have a table named Academic and the staff has a positionID but this positionID is:

```
tablePosition
----------------
PositionID
```

thats it...only one column

Comment: Pretty sure this could be closed as opinion-based. I could probably think of reasons why a table might only have one column, but anyone guessing at why that table in your system has only one column would be pure speculation. Could you maybe ask the person who created the table? Or check the system's documentation or data dictionary? (Yeah, most people don't have those, but this shows why they should.)

Comment: It could be a lookup list for a combo box.  It could be from normalisation (does the position disappear if no one's filling that position?).  Too many "could be" answers to be meaningful.

Comment: The foreign key constraints - to and from the table - (if there are any) could also help with how the table is used, if there is no documentation.

Answer (score 1):

My best and most speculative guesses are:

A lookup table. Used as a control/pick list for an application or report

A dimension.  Used in a data warehouse.

A log table. Used for logging.

Left over junk fron an adhoc query, data migration, report filter etc.

Aaron was right... But I couldn't resist ; )

To me, the names imply that it's to distinguish between academic and non academic staff. But unless you can test the application exhaustively in order to reverse engineer it you may never know the true/complete purpose for it.